# What CMS and Framework software suitable on same website

Tags: cms, framework, web-server

Recently I have been requested to develop a website which has a front end with static content and a backend with heavily dynamic content. The back-end may be used by 100s of users daily to upload data and view processed reports and charts.

The Client is suggesting to use a CMS like Drupal for the front end. They also suggest that the back-end be done with a framework like django or codeigniter.

While I am new to CMS, the idea of using a CMS for static seems not practical for me. It will be a waste of resources and time for a static content that may not change over much within 12 months.

What type of development tools / software should be used for both static and dynamic site of this client?

Comment: This kind of advice is off-topic here. Read the Help section.

Comment: I Have reworded  please check now

Comment: This site is not for the kind of guidance you seek. A Stack Exchange is designed for narrowly-focused on a specific problem that can reasonably be expected to be resolved with a short spot-on answer. The goal is to **avoid open-ended long-winded discussions**. You should seek a discussion or forum site, like http://www.CodeRanch.com/. On this particular Stack Exchange, you provide a detailed list of specific criteria by which you would consider a particular software product to have fulfilled your needs, and then we suggest possible products that fit. Your Question is wide-open and too broad.

Comment: What I need to know is whether it is the practice to have cms and framework together for single website. if so any example software/tools. I didn't feel any long discussion was needed for this.

Comment: Note that if you are going to use drupal, it can also be used as a framework in addition to a CMS. So my personal advice will be to choose drupal or django or anything else you prefer.

Comment: Thank you all for the useful ideas and comments